# PostgreSQL - how to execute "free-standing" code?

Tags: database, postgresql, codeblocks, plpgsql

I am used to the Query Editor in SQL Server where one can freely write & execute T-SQL. How do I get the following code to execute in PostgreSQL without having to create a function out of it?

```
DECLARE 
    l integer = 1;
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE product_i (id bigint, key integer, value integer);
    CREATE INDEX ix_product_i_size ON product_i(value) WHERE key = 1;
    CREATE INDEX ix_product_i_mass ON product_i(value) WHERE key = 2;

    LOOP
        BEGIN;
        INSERT
        INTO    product_i (id, key, value)
        SELECT  id, 1, CEILING(10 + RANDOM() * 90)
        FROM    generate_series(l, 1000) id;

        INSERT
        INTO    product_i (id, key, value)
        SELECT  id, 2, CEILING(10 + RANDOM() * 90)
        FROM    generate_series(l, 1000) id;

        COMMIT;
        l := l + 1000;
        EXIT WHEN l > 5000;
    END LOOP;
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using at least PostgreSQL 9.0, you can include this in a DO block:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-do.html

Comment: I'm using the latest version. However, the Query editor won't accept the initial "DO", stating: "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DO"
LINE 1: ...(ANALYZE off, VERBOSE off, COSTS on, BUFFERS off )DO $$DECLA..."

Comment: DO works fine, looks like a bug in your code or editor. The message about ANALYZE, VERBOSE, etc. looks like some EXPLAIN-stuff, why do you need that? And what editor do you use? Try pgAdmin, works fine.

Comment: Ok, I see F7 (explain) gives this error. Executing doesn't. Thanks @Derek.

Comment: @Frank I was using F7 to test if the syntax is ok, rather than trying to execute the code (I want to run it later but wanted to get it syntactically right now). Is there another way to test?

Comment: Try to wrap your do in transaction and roll it back to test it out. Like...BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DO $$DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE chicken();
END$$;
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

Comment: @StarShip3000 that will work fine. What I want it to do is commit every iteration of the loop.

Comment: In that case you will have to use pl/perlu or dblink to issue a commit in batches like that. Or write a script of some kind that calls your code. PostgreSQL executes PLGSQL function or DO statements in a single transaction.  Here's a link where I asked that question back in 2006 http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2006-09/msg01005.php

Comment: @lanC: commit in the loop is very bad practice in PostgreSQL. In contrast to SQL Server, committing very often will **slow** down your transaction. Only committing once will almost always be faster than committing in the loop.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what is best practice for massive bulk inserts, such as in the millions?

Comment: @lanC: yes, it's perfectly OK to commit million inserts only once